# Memory Allocation in Renderscript

Tags: android, memory-management, renderscript

I would like to better understand how memory allocation works in Renderscript.

First, I'd like to confirm if the memory is allocated at runtime or compile time.

The documentation states:

> Non-static, global variables that you declare in your RenderScript are
>   allocated memory at compile time.

Is this always the case?

And second, does Renderscript request memory allocated to Android VM or Android physical memory?

In the documentation I could only find the following:

> Applications that use RenderScript still run in the Android VM. The
>   actual RenderScript code, however, runs natively and needs access to
>   the memory allocated in the Android VM.

Which doesn't answer the above question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a script (cats.rs) with some globals like

```
int hats[4096];
char bats[32];
float rats;
// a bunch of kernels follow here
```

When you create a new `ScriptC_cats`, all of those buffers will be allocated as part of that script object; the size requirement is set at compile time and obeyed at instantiation, so the right thing will happen for you.

All RenderScript objects exist in two parts. First off, there's the API object, which is what you actually get handed back when call `RenderScript.create()` or `new ScriptC_cats`. Those API objects exist in the Dalvik heap and are very small (maybe a couple hundred bytes for the larger objects). Those API objects are tied to the native objects, which the Java APIs access via JNI. The native objects contain the actual backing store for your Allocations, actual bitcode for your kernels, etc.

Vendor drivers may put buffers into special places for their GPUs or things like that, but from an app developer POV that's equivalent to memory allocated outside of the Dalvik heap.

Comment: So, suppose we wish to handle large bitmaps, we could pass the input bitmap and immediately recycle it, and then give it a new output bitmap to put the data into (or actually not recycle at all, and just give the same bitmap object instead) ? This way, you won't have any time that you hold 2 bitmaps on dalvik VM heap memory, right?